# Kohana ORM Model not loading

Tags: kohana, kohana-orm

In the following code, the "add" action works as expected, but the remove action throws an error citing that Kohana "Cannot delete favorites model because it is not loaded."

Any ideas?

```
if ($_GET['action'] == 'add')
{
    $favorites = ORM::factory('favorites');
    $favorites->question_id = $_GET['question_id'];
    $favorites->user_id     = Kohana_Facebook::instance()->user_id();
    $favorites->save();
}
elseif ($_GET['action'] == 'remove')
{
$favorites = ORM::factory('favorites')
    ->where('user_id', '=', $facebook->user_id())
    ->and_where('question_id', '=', $_GET['question_id'])
    ->find();
$favorites->delete();
}
```

A `var_dump($favorites)` show this:

```
object(Model_Favorites)#24 (31) { 
["_table_name:protected"]=> string(9) "favorites" 
["_has_one:protected"]=> array(0) { } 
["_belongs_to:protected"]=> array(0) { } 
["_has_many:protected"]=> array(0) { } 
["_load_with:protected"]=> array(0) { } 
["_validation:protected"]=> NULL 
["_object:protected"]=> array(2) { ["user_id"]=> string(8) "60717257" ["question_id"]=> string(1) "2" } 
["_changed:protected"]=> array(0) { } 
["_related:protected"]=> array(0) { } 
["_valid:protected"]=> bool(false) 
["_loaded:protected"]=> bool(false) 
["_saved:protected"]=> bool(false) 
["_sorting:protected"]=> NULL 
["_foreign_key_suffix:protected"]=> string(3) "_id" 
["_object_name:protected"]=> string(9) "favorites" 
["_object_plural:protected"]=> string(11) "favoriteses" 
["_table_columns:protected"]=> array(2) { ["user_id"]=> array(13) { ["type"]=> string(3) "int" ["min"]=> string(11) "-2147483648" ["max"]=> string(10) "2147483647" ["column_name"]=> string(7) "user_id" 
["column_default"]=> NULL 
["data_type"]=> string(3) "int" 
["is_nullable"]=> bool(false) 
["ordinal_position"]=> int(1) 
["display"]=> string(2) "11" 
["comment"]=> string(0) "" 
["extra"]=> string(0) "" 
["key"]=> string(3) "PRI" 
["privileges"]=> string(31) "select,insert,update,references" } 
["question_id"]=> array(13) { ["type"]=> string(3) "int" ["min"]=> string(11) "-2147483648" ["max"]=> string(10) "2147483647" ["column_name"]=> string(11) "question_id" ["column_default"]=> NULL ["data_type"]=> string(3) "int" ["is_nullable"]=> bool(false) ["ordinal_position"]=> int(2) ["display"]=> string(2) "11" ["comment"]=> string(0) "" ["extra"]=> string(0) "" ["key"]=> string(3) "PRI" ["privileges"]=> string(31) "select,insert,update,references" } } ["_updated_column:protected"]=> NULL ["_created_column:protected"]=> NULL ["_primary_key:protected"]=> string(2) "id" ["_primary_key_value:protected"]=> NULL ["_table_names_plural:protected"]=> bool(true) ["_reload_on_wakeup:protected"]=> bool(true) ["_db:protected"]=> object(Database_MySQL)#23 (6) { ["_connection_id:protected"]=> string(40) "f9eb0f07846bef120d6d8414616f81f993f5306a" ["_identifier:protected"]=> string(1) "`" ["last_query"]=> string(98) "SELECT `favorites`.* FROM `favorites` WHERE `user_id` = '60717257' AND `question_id` = '2' LIMIT 1" ["_instance:protected"]=> string(7) "default" ["_connection:protected"]=> resource(73) of type (mysql link) ["_config:protected"]=> array(6) { ["type"]=> string(5) "mysql" ["connection"]=> array(3) { ["hostname"]=> string(9) "localhost" ["database"]=> string(17) "davekiss_dumbpoll" ["persistent"]=> bool(false) } ["table_prefix"]=> string(0) "" ["charset"]=> string(4) "utf8" ["caching"]=> bool(false) ["profiling"]=> bool(true) } } 
["_db_group:protected"]=> NULL 
["_db_applied:protected"]=> array(0) { } 
["_db_pending:protected"]=> array(0) { } 
["_db_reset:protected"]=> bool(true) 
["_db_builder:protected"]=> NULL 
["_with_applied:protected"]=> array(0) { } 
["_cast_data:protected"]=> array(0) { } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is not loaded in your code.

You need to add `find()` before your `delete()`

**UPD**:

As I can see - it is just a relation tables without single PK field (`id`)

You could delete row with something like:

```
DB::delete('favorites')->where('user_id', '=', $facebook->user_id())
                       ->and_where('question_id', '=', $_GET['question_id'])
                       ->execute(Database::instance());
```

Or you could use `remove()` method (since seems like you're using kohana ORM relations)

Comment: I've tried this to no avail. I've updated the code above to reflect this change. Same error.

Comment: @Dave Kiss: `var_dump($favorites);`

Comment: @zerkms - Thanks for the update - does ORM::delete not work with table that lack a single PK? I am trying to keep it all ORM for consistency.

Comment: @Dave Kiss: give a little more information about models then. The best way to do this is to write something like `$user->remove('question', $question);` where $user and $question are particular instances of entities that should be linked off. And `user` entity has `many-to-many` relation to `question` entity.

Comment: I've yet to implement any relationships between models since I don't fully understand yet how they work. Do you have any links to a comprehensive tutorial or better yet, provide a restructured demonstration in your answer using your suggestion above?

Comment: @Dave Kiss: you can start your diving into Kohana orm with https://github.com/jheathco/kohana-orm/wiki. After that it would be great to also examine source code for ORM and DB modules. They are not so difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Face same issue and fixed with the solution

add code like

protected $_primary_key = 'your tables primary key';

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue after loading my codes with `->where()` and `->find()`
Just make sure that the

`protected $_primary_key = 'id';`

is defined at the model.